# C++ Unable to assign Character Array Variable to String Variable

Tags: c++

I am in need of assistance.

I am trying to create a vector structure where the string contents inside of a char array get automatically assign to another STRING variable within the same structure.

After countless hours, I have not been able to figure it out. When I used function such as string(). It doesn't copy anything. I can't seem to assign char variable to string variable. Please advise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

const int NAME_SIZE = 25;

struct tableInfo
{
    char name2[NAME_SIZE];
    string name = str(name2); // I need name string to equal name2 character variable
    string info;
    string link;
};

vector<tableInfo> table(6);

bool compareByWord(const tableInfo &lhs, const tableInfo &rhs);



int main()
{
    cin.getline(table[0].name2, 51);
    cin.getline(table[1].name2, 51);
    cin.getline(table[2].name2, 51);
    cin.getline(table[3].name2, 51);
    cin.getline(table[4].name2, 51);


    sort(table.begin(), table.end(), compareByWord);

    cout << table[0].name << endl;
    cout << table[1].name << endl;
    cout << table[2].name << endl;
    cout << table[3].name << endl;
    cout << table[4].name << endl;

}


bool compareByWord(const tableInfo &lhs, const tableInfo &rhs)
{
    unsigned int length = lhs.name.length();

    if (rhs.name.length() < length)
        length = rhs.name.length();

    int sameLetters = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        if (sameLetters == length)
            return false;

        if (tolower(lhs.name[i]) == tolower(rhs.name[i]))
        {
            ++sameLetters;
            continue;
        }

        return(lhs.name[i] < rhs.name[i]);
            return(lhs.name[i] < rhs.name[i]);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use one or the other (preferably just the `std::string`)? Or use a member function?

Comment: Why do you need the same data twice in your structure? Is `str(name2` meant to copy the data? If so, when do you want it to run?

Comment: You can [overload operator >>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream_extraction_and_insertion).

Comment: what was the downvote for?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that there is a function implemented in `<algorithm>` for performing a lexicographical comparison [`lexicographical_compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/)

Comment: String() its not activating when inside of struct. My problems is that I need char to be converted to string upon user entering their name inside the structure to later to be sorted alphabetically with an algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to happen in a structure (or class), consider making sure it happens by using the constructor. You will need to change your vector so you can no longer default construct the struture, but that's ok.

This works, by enforcing the two fields contain identical data (not withstanding 25 no being long enough):

```
const int NAME_SIZE = 25;

struct tableInfo
{
    tableInfo(char * whatever); //Make it so
    char name2[NAME_SIZE];
    string name;
    string info;
    string link;
};


tableInfo::tableInfo(char *whatever)
    : name(whatever)
{
    strncpy(name2, whatever, NAME_SIZE);  //Now they match - unless whatever was too big
}

//vector<tableInfo> table(6);//no longer ok with the non-default constructor

bool compareByWord(const tableInfo &lhs, const tableInfo &rhs);

int main()
{
    vector<tableInfo> table;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        char name2[NAME_SIZE];
        cin.getline(name2, 51); //Do you really mean 51?
                                // It's smaller than NAME_SIZE
        table.emplace_back(name2);
    }

    sort(table.begin(), table.end(), compareByWord);

    cout << table[0].name << endl;
    cout << table[1].name << endl;
    cout << table[2].name << endl;
    cout << table[3].name << endl;
    cout << table[4].name << endl;

}
```

Comment: Can you please send me working code, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: This compiles - if you add your `compareByWord` function to the end. It might even work.

Comment: Thanks, your methods works! The problem was that I was trying to save a structure with a string variable to file. Unfortunately, it is not allowed by using the reinterpret cast, the problem was not in the string  conversion but file record reading. sorry for the confusion. You are really good!!

Comment: Glad we fixed it - watch out for the 51 v. NAME_SIZE

Answer (score 0):

How about doing like this:

```
struct tableInfo
{
    char name2[NAME_SIZE];
    string name;
    string info;
    string link;

    tableInfo(const char* in_name)
    {
        memset(name2, 0, NAME_SIZE);
        strncpy(name2, in_name, NAME_SIZE - 1);
        name = string(name2);
    }
};
```

How to use:

```
char tmp[NAME_SIZE];
cin.getline(tmp, 51);
table[0] = tableInfo(tmp);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what is in_name?

Comment: @Cristian325 whatever you want to pass in.

Answer (score 0):

I argue that you don't even need an array in the struct. Just use `std::string`. `getline` supports reading into a `std::string` and you can access individual characters using `str[]`. If you need to get a pointer to the data you can use `str.c_str()`.

If you *really* need to use an array in the struct you can create a member function to return a `std::string`:

```
struct tableName {
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    std::string info;
    std::string link;

    std::string nameString() const { return name; }
};
```

Comment: string name = string.getline(name2);  It doesn't work.

Comment: I am in need of char array variable to be copied to string variable.

Comment: You can read the data directly into the string with `std::getline` e.g. `std::getline(std::cin, table[0].name);` - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline
No need for an array.

Comment: I need the name to be first copied into a char array and then to a string variable for later alphabetic sorting.

Comment: Why? You can do the same thing with just a `std::string`. Is this some arbitrary requirement for an assignment?